# Where should ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit be set in an Azure Function app that IS NOT on a consumption plan?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I know that ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit is set to 50 for consumption plans.

Where can this be set for app service plan functions?

Answer (score 1):

This apparently not currently public for now to the Functions and fully managed by the cloud Host. Please refer to this issue comment: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/850#issuecomment-368078835

Quoting @brettsam :

> It is managed by Functions in production as the Web host increases this limit.

Comment: That's correct. There is no official way to manually set it currently. You should open an issue on the repo @Simon linked to. Otherwise when not running on consumption, you can compile the runtime yourself and run that instead of the default one, but that's obviously too inconvenient